# How to show/hide html controls keeping their locations the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-interface

Imagine search bar on html page, it has, say 4 controls on the same line, each wrapped in DIV.
E.g. a few listboxes on the same line:
**searchbyX, byY, byZ, byN**
After some clicks, some of these controls are hidden, some are displayed (using JQuery).
The problem is that I want each control to keep it's place, but if I hide it's left neighbour, it will move to the left, thus not keeping its original position.

How to show/hide controls keeping their locations the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly,

```
visibility: hidden
```

will do the trick.
It will hide the element, but reserve the space it needs.

To make it visible again, remove the property or set a explicit

```
visibility: visible
```

Comment: more correctly to what they asked, $(#element).css('visibility', 'hidden');

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding them by setting "display" to "none", set "visibility" to "hidden".